# Why is there a requireStatement ensuring currentOwner > LastOwner in the checkNSignatures() function on GlobalSafe.sol?

Tags: signature, multisignature

I'm trying to understand why this check exists. The function CheckNSignatures() loops through the "bytes memory signatures" param in the execTransaction() func[image]tion and validates each of the signatures. However when iterating over the next signature it ensures the signature that it's checking is greater than the signature it previously checked. Why is this needed?

Comment: could you let us see the whole code please

Answer (score 1):

[It](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/GnosisSafe.sol#L301)’s a simple and cheap way to ensure that the list of signers does not contain duplicates — instead of sorting in Solidity or writing some complex code to check for duplicates, expect the caller to (off-chain) sort the list of signatures in ascending signer order, pass them to the function sorted, and then on-chain simply verify that each signer is greater than the previous. If this condition is satisfied, it means that there are no duplicate signers.